# /var/adm/wtmpx: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: solaris

When typing in the command `last` on Solaris 10 I'm getting the error `/var/adm/wtmpx: Value too large for defined data type`.  How can I get `last` to display user logins etc., like it's supposed to?

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit as to what precisely you'd like us to help you with...

Answer (score 3):

You should use the command `fwtmp` to change the file.

You can use it as a filter to filter the wtmpx (which has some fixed block length). To keep the last 500 entries:

```
< /var/adm/wtmpx fwtmp | tail -500 > /var/tmp/tailwtmp
cat /var/tmp/tailwtmp | fwtmp -ic > /var/adm/wtmpx
```

You might have to specify the full path to fwtmp (`/usr/lib/acct/fwtmp`) depending on your PATH env var.

A man page for fwtmp can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/wtmpfix-1m.html)

Comment: @PhilipKearns The commandline did not get mangled. I accepted your suggestion to remove the redundant cat, but I prefer to have the input redirect before the command.

Comment: OK, never seen that syntax before.